# Callback function is not executed within returned Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, callback, amazon-route53

I have two functions that return promise. The first one provide host value, and the second one use the host value to get IP address. I can see that the first function is running without any issue. But looks like the callback function side `getHostIps` is not executed at all. Not sure why it happens....what's wrong with my promise function?

my promise chain:

```
getHostedZoneId(dns)
.then(hostZoneId => {
   getHostIps(dns, hostZoneId);
})
.then(hostIps => {
    logger.Info(hostIps); //hostIps is undefined
})
.catch(err => logger.error(err));
```

getHostedZoneId:

```
var getHostedZoneId = function(dns) {
    var params = {
        DNSName: dns,
    };
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      findHostZoneByDNS(params, function(err, data) {
            if(err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            else {
                resolve(data);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

getHostIps:

```
var getHostIps = function(dns, hostZoneId) {
    var params = {
        HostedZoneId: hostZoneId,
        StartRecordName: dns,
    };
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      findHostIps(params, function(err, data) {
           //logger.info("get there");
            if(err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            else {
                resolve(data);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I logged hostIps and err and data, all of them are defined. So I am sure that the callback function inside promise is not executed. But not sure how to fix it.

Any feedback is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: you fixed the missing return. you should edit it then. so your problem changes you receive undefined (`logger.Info(hostIps); //hostIps is undefine`) for the argument. something is with `findHostIps(params, function(err, data) {` wrong. can you provide that code

Comment: you possibly are doing *something wrong™* in `findHostIps` - but you haven't shown that function, so, I'm *guessing™*

Comment: Perhaps my comment was vague ... what is the code for `findHostIps` - please share it in your question, it's clearly not calling the callback for some reason

Comment: Where is the value of `dns` in `getHostIps(dns, hostZoneId)` coming from? (The `dns` parameter of `getHostedZoneId(dns)` is not in scope)

Comment: Hi All, the problem is solved. I am writing my code based on previous shitty code which is written by previous eng in the team. After I delete his code, everything works fine. I think there might be some race condition issue in the js file...

Answer (score 1):

You have to return the promise from your then statement to complete the chain.

```
getHostedZoneId(dns)
.then(hostZoneId => {
   return getHostIps(dns, hostZoneId); // Add return
})
.then(hostIps => {
    logger.Info(hostIps);
})
.catch(err => logger.error(err));
```

Comment: Hi Jordan, thanks for helping. I add return but the callback is still not executed :/